# What could be the possible causes of a "java.io.IOException: Bad HTTP request, less data is received than expected" error?

Tags: java, http

I have a GlassFish server with a lot of "java.io.IOException: Bad HTTP request, less data is received than expected" errors in an application instance log.

Anyone knows what could be the possible causes of this error?

It sounds like the http request sent from the client is malformed, isn't it?

Comment: Yes. It is malformed.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the http header does not correspond with what is in the body.

Comment: Specifically the Content-Length header.

Comment: Indeed, thanks I was too lazy to search the name of the field :).